# How to make a pod accessible from outide with a Load Balancer (or directly)?

Tags: kubernetes, load, google-kubernetes-engine

Here is what I'm trying to do with a Kubernetes config file:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub
  labels:
    app: selenium-hub
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-hub
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: selenium-hub
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: selenium-hub
        image: selenium/hub
        ports:
          - containerPort: 4444
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "1000Mi"
            cpu: ".5"
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /wd/hub/status
            port: 4444
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /wd/hub/status
            port: 4444
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 4444
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4444
  selector:
    app: selenium-hub
  type: LoadBalancer
```

In GKE it creates an app with a pod, then a Load Balancer with an external IP. But when I'm trying to access the app from outside through `http://LBIP:port` it doesn't work.

So how I can expose the pod I created in first place? Do I need a LB if I'm using only one replica?

Comment: Please add ``` (three backticks) before and after your code so the indentation is preserved. Also please share your code in the question description instead of the title. All of this will make it easier for us to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum well... hum... you'll laugh! On my side I didn't laugh...

It was a network issue. Don't know why but my house IP address seems to be, for an obscure reason, blacklisted from accessing any instances on GCP. The console no issue, but when trying to go through the http via my browser it doesn't connect at all.

Use of a nordvpn is working! So far so good.

Anyway thx for you help guys!

Answer (score -1):

Looking at specs, I don't see any problem. Check few things -

1. Does your pod is in Running state with exposed port 4444?
2. Can you access your pod locally using ClusterIP:port?

You can expose your pod using NodePort service also but in production NodePort service is not a recommended way to expose app to outside cluster.

Comment: Hello, first thx man I apreciate you wanna help me.

To answer your questions, I did a port-foward of the POD with:
- kubectl port-forward $PODNAME 4444:4444
- And yes if do that in a separated terminal on the master : curl http://localhost:4444 it works!

But if I try to access through curl http://ClusterIP:4444 if freeze...

I tried to create a NodePort but should I change something on the LB YAML file? I mean I can't access external through the LB endpoint no matter what... even if the port-forward is activated so... I'm lost lol

Comment: Just to mention: If I create a NodePort and an ingress on top of that it works, but it's not what I want here...